# convert string to _T in cpp

Tags: c++, windows

I want to convert `string` or `char*` to the `_T` but not able to do.

if i write

```
_tcscpy(cmdline,_T ("hello world"));
```

it works perfectly, but if i write

```
char* msg="hello world";
_tcscpy(cmdline,_T (msg));
```

it shows an error like: `error C2065: 'Lmsg' : undeclared identifier`

Please give me a solution.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Use **const** `char* msg`; string literals are read only.

Comment: Or use `const wchar_t* msg = L"hello world";` and the problem is gone!

Comment: +1 for Bo Persson's solution. Just go 100% Unicode. It supports every language, and that includes English. The 1 byte saving you get by using ASCII for your English release and Unicode for all others really isn't worth the headaches you'll get.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`_T` is a macro, defined as (if `UNICODE` is defined):

```
#define _T(a)  L ## a
```

which can work only with string-literals. So when you write `_T("hi")` it becomes `L"hi"` which is valid, as expected. But when you write `_T(msg)` it becomes `Lmsg` which is an undefined identifier, and you didn't intend that.

All you need is this function [`mbstowcs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy.aspx) as:

```
const char* msg="hello world"; //use const char*, instead of char*
wchar_t *wmsg = new wchar_t[strlen(msg)+1]; //memory allocation
mbstowcs(wmsg, msg, strlen(msg)+1);

//then use wmsg instead of msg
_tcscpy(cmdline, wmsg);

//memory deallocation - must do to avoid memory leak!
 delete []wmsg;
```

Answer (score 3):

`_T` only works with string literals. All it does is turn the literal into an `L""` string if the code's being compiled with Unicode support, or leave it alone otherwise.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [mbtowcs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function.

You should also look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc).

Comment: +1, those functions are deprecated. Instead use this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyktyxsx(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Yes, of course. But that would have confused the OP. I tried to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

`_T` is a macro that makes string literals into wide-char string literals by prepending an `L` before the literal in `UNICODE` builds.

In other words, when you write `_T("Hello")` it is as if you had written `"Hello"` on an ANSI build or `L"Hello"` on a UNICODE build. The type of the resulting expression is `char*` or `wchar_t*` respectively.

`_T` **can not** convert a string *variable* (`std::string` or `char*`) to a `wchar_t*` -- for this, you have to use a function like [`mbstowcs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy.aspx) or [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Suggestion:** It will be much easier for you (and in no way worse) to always make a UNICODE build and forget about `_T`, `TCHAR` and all other `T`-derivatives. Just use wide-character strings everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

`_T` is not an actual type. It's a macro that prepends *string literals* with `L` so that they would be `wchar_t*`s instead of `char*`. If you need to convert a `char*` string to `wchar_t*` one at runtime, you need [mbtowcs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for example.

Answer (score 1):

The _T modifier is just a declaration to tell the compiler that the string literal must be interpreted as a utf-16 encoding. The reason it doesn't work on the variable is because the contents of that variable have already been declared as ascii.

As already mentioned the [mbstowcs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function is what you need to perform the conversion of a char data into utf-16 (wide char) data.